# Editing two layer at same time using QGIS

Tags: qgis

How can  Iedit two layer at the same time?

I have node, link layer.

If I edit a node's location, then that should change the link layer automatically.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In ArcGIS shared geometry editing can be done when feature classes participate in either a map topology or a geodatabase topology.

Comment: Did you try with the node tools and the setting of linking nodes ? https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#node-tool

Comment: @Maximilienjaffrès that works - you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I put it in the comment and as it was confirmed it's the right thing :

You should look in the settings of Qgis and enable snapping

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#setting-the-snapping-tolerance-and-search-radius

then you can use the "node tool" and move several vertexs at the same time

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#node-tool

Also if you double click on a geometry border with the node tool, it will add a node in the border of the geometry, you may need this tip if your linestring doesn't have a vertex at the intersection.